# On mouse down, click event is getting triggered in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Click event is getting triggered on mouse down event. Is there any way to cancel the click event and just trigger the mouse down event?

```
 <div onClick={this.onClick}
      onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}> </div>
```

I am using react 16.

Comment: Show the full code

Comment: Why do you want `mouseDown` **and** `click`?

Comment: have you done the `preventDefault();` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: preventDefault won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is have separate nested `div` for different events:

```
<div onClick={this.onClick}> 
     <div onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}> </div>
</div>
```

And then, can use [**stopPropagation()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the events like this:

```
 onMouseDown: function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('onMouseDown');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Click event occurs when `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` occurs on an event. So when you trigger a click event, first a `mouseDown` event is fired. You can put a function on `onMouseUp` event so that it gets triggered when the mouse button is released.